# Having an error in my first selenium program

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

**CODE**

```java
package testing;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class demooo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           System.out.println("hi");
           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\kavya\\Downloads\\
           chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe");
           WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
           driver.get("https://www.gmail.com/");
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/io/ByteStreams
```

Comment: And what is your question? Please read [ask] and the [tour] and [edit] your question to provide an actual question that can be answered. Stack Overflow is not a code writing/debugging service.

Answer (score 1):

Exception  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/io/ByteStreams`  indicates that your project is missing the `Guava` library which is a required dependency for `Selenium`, in the context of using `ChromeDriver`

Add the following to your pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>32.1.2-jre</version>
</dependency>
```